# What may cause Long-Running Tests problem, when deploying code to Production

Tags: unit-test

I tried to deploy code. Despite of "Method defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" I had Long-Running Tests warning label. It said: "The following tests have long execution times. To improve each tests's performance, be sure to follow Apex and SOQL best practices. To learn more, see Performance Tuning Resources for Long_Running Tests"

class_name.method_name  3 min 14 sec

This method runs for 0 seconds in sandbox. It doesn't use Org's data (no SeeAllData=true). However, I think it might be because it deals with Attachment object. However, the body of Attachment is 'qwerty'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Suggest you extract the method being tested and the test method and post those - nothing comes to mind for me based on your description of the problem. Did you get the problem once or multiple times?

Comment: @KeithC, this is the first time. This test and class, which it is testing, were deployed one week ago. It worked before rolling out new Salesforce version (this Monday I notices v.35). I blame v.35 :-)

Comment: When servers are busy priority is given to interactive use ahead of activities like deployments (including the tests that are run). So you may have just been unlucky at the time you deployed and if you deployed again would see normal performance. This [Asynchronous Processing in Force.com](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_async_processing.pdf) is worth a read to get a sense that asynchronous activities can get seriously delayed.